# jQuery datepicker default value in html input filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

jQuery datepicker default (today) in input field

[image]

Comment: hello dear, this my question. not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Use `setDate` and `new Date()` for setting current date

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Comment: it's don't comfort with my current jQ version. find another solution. `$('#datepicker').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', '0');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(function () {
             var currentDate = new Date();
             $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                 inline: true,
                 showOtherMonths: true,
                 dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
             });
             $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
         })
```

Html Code

```
     <tr>
        <td width="190"><input style="width: 85px; color:#27AAE1; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;" type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```